# Error in rewrite rule in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I was getting problem in `htaccess`. I have tried a lot examples but yet not able to write perfect `Rewrite Rules` as I want. Please help me.

> http://domainname.com/sub-category.php?mc=eatry
>
> to
>
> http://domainname.com/eatry

AND

> http://domainname.com/explorelisting.php?mc=eatry&&sc=restaurant
>
> to
>
> http://domainname.com/eatry/restaurant

**.htaccess (I have tried)**

---

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/(.*) ./sub-category.php?mc=$1
RewriteRule ^/(.*) ./explorelisting.php?mc=$1&&sc=$1
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things to note.
In the URL you don't need `&&` only `&` when specifying another parameter.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(\w+)       sub-category.php?mc=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+) explorelisting.php?mc=$1&sc=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

The regular expression assumes that the query will only accept any letter - capital or lowercase.

`RewriteCond` is used to check that the URL is not a directory and not a file, if it isn't, then it rewrites to the rule.
This is used because the URL `http://www.example.com/index` would get redirected to `http://www.example.com/sub-category.php?mc=index` which is undesired.

It might be prudent to restructure your rule. Perhaps having the URLs looking like `http://www.example.com/category/eatry` and then modifying the first rule to being `RewriteRule ^category/(\w+) sub-category.php?mc=$1` in order to prevent ambiguity.

The [flags](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html) (what is at the end of each rule in square brackets) are as follows:

- `QSA` - Query String Append:
  This enables you to have the parameters at the end of the string (anything following the `?`).
- `NC` - No Case:
  This means that your rule is case insensitive.
- `L` - Last:
  This will terminate the htaccess if the rule is matched.